# end task vs end process

Tags: windows, process, task-manager

Why is it that ending a task in XP/Vista takes so much longer than ending the underlying process itself?  WHat's the relationship between a task and a process from an OS perspective?

Answer (score 7):

"Task" is the term used by "Task Manager" to

- justify its name
- show the list of "main windows of the user's processes"(*), if any

"End Task" gives the "task" (message loop for the "main window") a last chance to react to the WM_CLOSE message and times-out on the associated process to finish. (See [Why can't you trap TerminateProcess?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040722-00/?p=38373) on Raymond Chen's blog, Old New Thing)

"End Process" is a rude TerminateProcess, discarding any pending changes to files or other resources.

Commonly, a mini-dump is created for a Microsoft Online Crash Analysis (Dr. Watson) report, which also might take a second or two.

(*) Raymond, I know this is so inaccurate.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that "end process" is that violent, it seems to wait a moment for the program to terminate anyway. It seems like, at least, since it takes more time, compared to Process Explorer (which is clearly not giving a chance and sending a "kill" command). Though I could be wrong, it's only a personal observation.

Comment: There is certainly a difference in the way end task behaves between process explorer and the standard WinTask Manager.  I think process explorer has implemented the rudest method to terminate a running PID.

Answer (score 4):

I believe ending the task requests the program to quit gracefully first, whereas ending the process is the Windows equivalent of SIGKILL - the OS just dumps the process with no questions asked.